# Not able to load Linkedin API via javascript

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

this code doesn't work for me, don't show error, nothing...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: xxxxxxxxxxx
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.API.Raw("/companies/xxxxxxx:(num-followers)");
   .result( function(result) { document.getElementById("statusDiv").innerHTML = result; } )
   .error( function(error) { /* do nothing */ } );
}
</script>
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you are close. According to the [Manual](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapiraw) you are right for your Raw Method. But look at

```
IN.API.Raw("/companies/xxxxxxx:(num-followers)");
```

remove the ";" so it reads:

```
IN.API.Raw("/companies/xxxxxxx:(num-followers)")
```

as I don't have a dev key for linked in I can't validate or go any farther.